# Xcode: Provisioning profile doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am developing an iOS app and have successfully built and ran the project on various devices. I was able to build and run the project just a few days ago, however, I am getting the error:

```
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.mitchellwolfe.frictionless-access-iphone" doesn't support the Keychain Sharing capability. (in target 'frictionless-access-iphone')
```

and

```
error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: com.mitchellwolfe.frictionless-access-iphone" doesn't include the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements. (in target 'frictionless-access-iphone')
```

No changes have been made since last successful build. This error affects 
all projects.

These are the actions I've already tried

- Double checking the bundle identifier in build settings and info.plist
- Deleting the provisioning profiles and had them regenerate
- Restarting Xcode
- adding `$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)$(BUNDLE_SUFFIX)` to bundle identifier info.plist
- switching to `build legacy system`
- switching between manual and automatic signing

After scouring the internet, I still couldn't find a working solution? Any suggestions on what I should do to fix this error?